# Secondary internet backup for ISP blackout

Tags: backup, internet, isp

We have a internet backup when 1st internet get shutdown(outage), but during ISP blackout the internet doesn't switch because its set up in a way to ping the default gateway but u can still ping it during ISP blackout. So I wanted to ask is there any solution to it so it switches to secondary ISP during the 1st ISP blackout and jump back when it loads again? Thank you for your time

Comment: Easiest way is you need a firewall that detect the link status.

Comment: @yagmoth555 But if the ISP's router fails, there is still an active link, just it won't go anywhere, and the firewall will stay fat dumb and happy.

Comment: @tsc_chazz You use your own router ? The question didnt state he use the ISP router. The ISP gear can be set in bridge mode usually to allow tou to use your own stuff, a lot of router allow the use of multiple WAN inside of them

Comment: @yagmoth555 There is always a router somewhere in the ISP's space. In our case we had modems from the ISPs connected directly to firewall Linux boxes, and even when the ISP was having trouble, because the router on the ISP's premises that the modem talked to had failed, the modem showed a link... so failover on link status alone will very often not work.

Answer (score 1):

We actually did have a setup like this for a while, and made that one work by pinging not the gateway, but another public IP that we also owned - our web server was off-site, and we would ping that. Do not try to do this by having your ISP1 host ping your ISP2 host; if either ISP1 or ISP2 goes down, it will look like they've both failed and your failover will just give up.